# How to create custom nested validator with JSR 303?

Tags: hibernate-validator

I am using Hibernate Validator - 5.2.2 (JSR 303).

I am doing a cross field validation, so I need to create a custom validator.

However I have no idea how to do the custom conditional nested validation.

example:

```
@ValidChildrenIfEnabled
public class MainDto {

    public boolean isEnabled;
    public List<Child> children;
}

public class Child {

    @NotBlank
    public String name;

    @Range(min = 1, max = 3)
    public int age;
}
```

If I don't need conditional validation, I would put 
@Valid on top of "children".

```
@Valid
public List<Child> children;
```

Note: I know how to create a custom validator, I just don't know how to create a custom validator that do nested validation that take advantage of existing built-in validator. Thanks!

EDIT:

My payload actually has one more payload, let's say SuperDto.

```
public class SuperDto {

    @Valid
    public List<MainDto> mainDtos;
}
```

And I do validation like this:

```
validator.validate(superDto);
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting use case. Unfortunately, I don't think you can do what you want to do as you can't trigger a validation from isValid().

Supposing that you have other constraints you want to validate in every cases, I think the best workaround is probably to use groups. And to use different groups depending of if isEnabled is true or not.

Anyway, you would have to special case how this bean is validated.

Comment: I have thought about using group, but I can't wrap around my head to use grouping. Actually the real life payload has one level up. So the grouping method quickly become complex.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why grouping would be complex for you. Could you explain it a bit more? Btw, what you have to understand is that it's the only way to condition some constraints. In your example, even if we provide you a way to trigger the validation from the class level constraint, you will still have a big problem: HV will validate the property level constraints anyway.

Comment: I am assuming that I need to assign MainDto to a group during compile time, right? However I receive MainDto as a input payload from REST api. As a result I cannot pre-assign a group from MainDto. Unless there's a way to assign grouping during runtime.